# Eclipse: Get the latest SVN revision of all projects

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, revision

Setup: 
Multiple Java projects in Eclipse with SVN Subclipse Plugin

When resolving tickets, I need the latest revision number of all projects.

Example: 
Projekt A, revision number 1

Projekt B, revision number 2

Projekt C, revision number 3

=> latest revision number: 3

Is there an elegant way to get the latest revision number (3 in the example) in Eclipse? I don't want to use cmd or something.

Comment: The latest SVN revision number of a SVN repository is shown in the _SVN Repository_ view. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: In that view I'm only able to see the revision number for each single resource, right? I'm actually looking for the "major" revision number for all commited projects.

Comment: Never mind, it's really in the SVN Repository view when I right click on the repository -> show history. Thanks. :)

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **latest SVN revision** number of a SVN repository is shown **in the *SVN Repository* view**: The revision number of a folder or of *trunk* is the highest revision number of all files in it.